# DecisionTrees - how to find the number of leafs in the tree?

Tags: scikit-learn

After training a random forest, I would like to know what is the number of leafs for every tree in the forest.

For example, If I trained a forest with 10 trees, I would like to get a vector with 10 entries, where the i-th entry is the number of leafs in the i-th tree.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the implementation of the [export_graphviz](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L45) method of the trees of the ensemble to understand how to unpack the tree datastructure.

A sample usage of the `export_graphviz` method is provided in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/tree.html#classification).